# {sf} monitor rowwise progress of reading shapefile with sf::st_read

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar, r-sf

I'm trying to monitor the progress of reading a shapefile (.shp) with sf::st_read. `st_read` offers five class-specific methods to dispatch:

```
# > methods(sf::st_read)
# [1] st_read.character*            st_read.DBIObject*           
# [3] st_read.default*              st_read.Pool*                
# [5] st_read.PostgreSQLConnection*
```

... of which st_read.DBIObject seems to be the appropriate one (shapefiles are bundled with a dbase-format database). `getAnywhere(st_read.DBIObject)` returns the function body, which contains some column-wise screening (e. g. to find the geometry column) - but I was not able to detect any row(=dataset)-oriented code to exploit for **monitoring the dataset ingestion**. Very grateful for your suggestions!

P.S. my goal is to more accurately drive the progress indicator in a shiny app when loading a shapefile. More accurately meaning beyond a spinner, elapsed fraction of previously measured loading duration or similar.

Answer (score 0):

`sf::read` delegates .shp data sources to `rgdal::readOGR` which, after determening i.a. the count of features contained in the shapefile loops through the features (which consumes a substantial part of the overall loading time). I modified the source to emit iteration step by total feature count throughout the loop as a proxy for loading progress.

Comment: Can you post the code you used for your fix?